# How can I shorten the Button? So far I created a button but as of now the background color is extended way past normal range

Tags: html, css

[image]My button's background color so far is extended way too far out on both right and left side. I tried to fix it but when i do, the button ends up going way too far left or right. I used a Width option to fix it but no luck. What can i do to fix the problem.

```css
.destination-reccomendations{
    background-image: url(Images/*****************);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.dr-text{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
}
.dr-text h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.dr-text h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.button{
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.button-text h1{
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="destination-reccomendations">
        <div class="dr-text">
            <h1>Explore the Beauty of our State</h1>
            <h3>Read more about destinations and reccomendations</h3>
            <div class="button">
                <div class="button-text">
                    <h1>Read More</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can't you just use `button` tag ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce your padding on the .dr-text and .dr-text h3 CSS attributes. Thats what causing the large size of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the with of your button and keep it centered by changing your class :

```
.button{
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Here's a snippet.

```css
.destination-reccomendations{
    background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/800x405/8a8a8a/fff&text=+);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.dr-text{
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
}
.dr-text h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.dr-text h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.button{
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.button-text h1{
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="destination-reccomendations">
        <div class="dr-text">
            <h1>Explore the Beauty of our State</h1>
            <h3>Read more about destinations and reccomendations</h3>
            <div class="button">
                <div class="button-text">
                    <h1>Read More</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```